# Correct way to use delaying method in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an adndroid application which will shows a distance from moment when I started the app.
I'm using Location Manager and this is my idea:

1. Check coordinates.
2. (2 sec delay)
3. Chceck coordinates2
4. If coordinates2 != coordinates then calculate distance between them and add it to double distance.
5. Repeat

   public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {

   ```
           sz = location.getLatitude();
           dl = location.getLongitude();

           String dls = String.valueOf(dl);
           String szs = String.valueOf(sz);

           aktualna_dlg.setText(dls);
           aktualna_szg.setText(szs);

           lat1 = location.getLatitude();
           lon1 = location.getLongitude();

           int secs = 2; // Delay in seconds

           Utils.delay(secs, new Utils.DelayCallback() {

               @Override
               public void afterDelay() {
                  lat2 = location.getLatitude();
                  lon2 = location.getLongitude();
               }
           });

           if (lat1!=lat2 || lon1!=lon2){
               distance += DistanceCalculator.distance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2, "K");
           }
           if(distance<1000){
               String distance_s = String.valueOf(distance*1000);
               distance_tv.setText(distance_s + " m");
           }
           else if(distance>=1000){
               String distance_s = String.valueOf(distance/1000);
               distance_tv.setText(distance_s + " km");
           }
       }
   ```

   But when I compile the app and catch GPS, I'm getting a distance ~ 6km. 
   What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what utils.delay does, since it isn't part of the framework.  But assuming it works correctly-  it happens on a delay.  That means lat2 and lon2 won't update until its called.  All of the code that uses those variables has to happen in afterDelay, they aren't valid until then.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate the delays and simply compare the argument to `onLocationChanged` with the argument from the last time it was called.  As for why you're recording a huge distance traveled...

**Use a high-pass filter**

How far do you expect to move in 2 seconds?  Probably less than your GPS receiver's accuracy, unless you're in an aircraft.  Most of your "movement" is actually just random noise.

In one of my apps, I save the starting GPS location as a point of reference.  On each call to `onLocationChanged`, I compute the distance between the current location and the point of reference.  If the distance is larger than some high-pass value, I add the distance to the running total and set the new location as the point of reference.  I use 100 meters as my high-pass value because I've seen a few devices with 100 meter accuracy or worse around tall buildings.

Comment: I tried this way but it didn't work... Could you write number points with this solution for me? This is how I see it: in onLocationChanged i assign new coordinates to reference and to current location so how can they be different?